# Cannot build project

Tags: android, gradle

I trying to assemble my project, but I only get an error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':basetools:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> No slave process to process jobs, aborting
```

I didn't change anything in my gradle files but abruptly got this error.

I already tried invalidate cahces and restart, rebuild

What should I do to fix it?

This is my project's build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    apply from: 'scripts/dependencies.gradle'
    apply from: 'scripts/testDependencies.gradle'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath plugin.android
        classpath plugin.fabric
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "1000" // or whatever number you want
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is a build.project of app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

def mainKeystore = file("../main.keystore")
//def debugKeystore = file("../debug.keystore")

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ilyinp.valutetracker"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile mainKeystore
            keyAlias "valutetracker"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        incremental = false
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile project(base.baseTools)
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0"

    compile dep.dagger.lib
    kapt dep.dagger.apt

    compile dep.moxy.lib
    compile dep.moxy.appCompat
    kapt dep.moxy.apt

    compile(dep.crashlytics) {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And finally, build.gradle of module `basetools`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile dep.support.multiDex
    //    compile dep.support.appCompat
    compile dep.support.cardView
    compile dep.support.recyclerView
    compile dep.support.design
    compile dep.support.constraintLayout
    compile dep.glide.lib
    compile dep.glide.transformations
    compile dep.rxjava.lib
    compile dep.rxjava.android
    compile dep.rxjava.permissions
    compile dep.rxjava.binding
    compile dep.rxjava.bindingCompat
    compile dep.retrofit.lib
    compile dep.retrofit.converter.gson
    compile dep.retrofit.adapter.rxjava
    compile dep.okhttp.lib
    compile dep.okhttp.interceptor.logging
    compile dep.dagger.lib
    kapt dep.dagger.apt
    compile dep.timber
    compile dep.moxy.lib
    compile dep.moxy.appCompat
    kapt dep.moxy.apt
    compile dep.materialDialogs
    compile dep.parceler.lib
    kapt dep.parceler.apt
    compile dep.cicerone
    compile(dep.fastadapter) {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile(dep.fastadapterCommons)
    compile(dep.fastadapterExtensions)
    compile(dep.materialize) {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile(dep.crashlytics) {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Sorry, I already tried it

Comment: post your gradle file @P. Ilyin

Comment: I posted build.gradle files

Comment: I faced this issue , just restarted android studio and working fine for me.

Comment: This was an issue in android gradle plugin 3.0.0, could you try with the newest alphas? It should be fixed there and you won't have to disable anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
minifyEnabled true
```

to

```
minifyEnabled false
```

if above changes does not work then try this as well

```
shrinkResources true
```

to

```
shrinkResources false
```

Comment: But it will increase size of my .apk! There is really no other way?

Comment: Well, `shrinkResources false` really helped, though by price of 35 kb :(

Comment: 1. Delete build folder manually (project's build and modules' build)
2. Invalidate Caches / Restart
Solve my problem, minifyEnabled/shrinkResources  are not necessary

Answer (score 6):

Go to Android Studio,  click "File" and click "Invalidate Caches / Restart...". This will work.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Android Studio wasn't enough to resolve this error for me: I also had to kill an `aapt2` process which had been left behind.

Comment: what version of android gradle plugin were you using?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska 3.0.1 on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Same issue. Invalidate caches and restart done the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete **build folder** in project and modules. After **Invalidate Caches and Restart** , it work for me!

You can try it

Answer (score 0):

'Clean Project'、'rebuild project' doesn't work.I solved this problem by invalidate  and restart

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete build folder manually (project's build and modules' build)
2. Delete old .impl file
3. Restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I was going through some RnD and applied above nothing worked, rather that made my project to crash completely and re do.
I was not shutting down and restart the system everyday.
When I got the next time **I simply** didn't do anything but **restarted the system**. It worked fine!!..

Guys , keep in mind : **Invalidate Caches and Restart** will make you loose  complete history of code changes.

**shrinkResources**  to false /
**minifyEnabled** to false will cost you few kbs of apk size